# How to push a value to an array using NodeJS and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update an array that is available on my MongoDB.
I tried the way below but I reive the message "Cannot read property push of undefined"

```
router.get("/candidatarse/:id", eCandidato, (req,res)=>{
Vaga.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).then((vaga)=>{
    
    vaga.candidatos.push(req.user._id)

    vaga.save().then(()=>{
    req.flash("success_msg","Você se candidatou com sucesso! Continue encaminhando seu curriculo.")
    res.redirect("/")
}).catch((err)=>{
    req.flash("error_msg", "Houve um erro ao cadastrar candidatura: "+err)
    res.redirect("/")
})
})
```

})

I also tried adding a position but didn't worked: `vaga.candidato[0].push(req.user.id)`

Here is how I have created the model:
[image]

Comment: what is `any` property in schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `vage` object, if it already includes `candidatos` just push new item to this array, else create new array for `candidatos`

```js
if (Array.isArray(vaga.candidatos) {
  vaga.candidatos.push(req.user._id);
} else {
  vaga.candidatos = [req.user._id];
}
```

Comment: Hi, looks like that worked, but the data has been not inserted. Looking in MongoDB I received an Object, but there is no data available after inserting it. I've checked and there is data when inserting, but that is not saving. I also tried to change the model to 'type: Array'. Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: I used "Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(vaga.candidatos)))" and worked, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

At the line 16, im not sure if "any: array" exist because any and array are two data types.
Try to remove that line.

Comment: The guy above helped regarding adding, but that is not adding exactly, as I mentioned on the comments, I guess that it is connected with what you said, I tried changing the model to 'Array' only, and I received an error saying that cannot cast, so I tried to String as well and didn't worked as well.